# using jquery/bootstrap, save data without using checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building a scheduling feature that shows Monday through Friday and a list of default times to select for appointments for 3 straight months.

Every user can select upto only two times a day. They also have Choose your own option to select other appointment times. Also they can select No Monday to say they dont need appointments for that day.

The problem I am having is I do not want to have a checkbox/radio for users to select the time. They just need to click on the time shown/Choose to select the time.

How do I acheive this, so I can take this data and save it to my database.

I have attached the mockup as an image below.

[image: MOCKUP IMAGE]

Thanks in advance.

I am having a form using PHP and when a user clicks on a 05:00a - 8:00a

tag, i am using jquery to update the value of hidden input with id= monday1 with 05:00a - 8:00a. But when a user tries multiple appointments, I am confused how to save the second appointment. Also how do i deselect an appointment when they make edits?? Which would be a cleaner way to do this??

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="monday1" name="monday1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="monday2" name="monday2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="tuesday1" name="tuesday1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="tuesday2" name="tuesday2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="wednesday1" name="wednesday1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="wednesday2" name="wednesday2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="thursday1" name="thursday1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="thursday2" name="thursday2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="friday1" name="friday1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="friday2" name="friday2" value="">

    <div class="row" id="days">
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-2" id="mon">
            MONDAY
            <div id="finaldates"></div>

            <p id="mone">05:00a - 8:00a</p>
            <p id="mtwo">05:30a - 8:30a</p>
            <p id="mthree">06:00a - 9:00a</p>
            <p id="mfour">07:00a - 10:00a</p>

            <p id="mfive">10:00a - 1:00p</p>
            <p id="msix">10:00a - 2:00p</p>

            <div class="buffer"></div>
            <img src="pics/PM-icon.png">

            <p id="mseven">03:00p - 6:00p</p>
            <p id="meight">03:30p - 6:30p</p>
            <p id="mnine">04:00p - 7:00p</p>

            <p id="choosemon">Choose Your Own</p>
            <p id="nomon">NO MONDAYS</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What code do you have?

Comment: If you are new to jQuery I'd suggest you read through the event handling, data-attributes and ajax call first. If you have tried anything else then please share with us so we can know where you stuck exactly.